# std::vector capacity gets way too large

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stdvector

So there's this problem with std::vector in vc++ I've faced. In g++ it works fine, however in vc++ after inserting 6 elements and calling a constructor the capacity has a value of over 1000000000 and shrink_to_fit() crashes my program. I don't know what causes this, but I'm going to post the code for the cause:

This code initializes the vector:

```
std::vector<unsigned> indices_rect {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};
```

Then this static function gets called, it justs sets a string for a default path:

```
engine::Texture::set_default_texture("../res/textures/engine/default_texture.jpg", engine::ImageType::JPG);
```

After this the capacity of indices_rect is still 6, just like the size.
But immediately as I jump into the constructor for "Shaderfile", before the first line is executed, the capacity is set to said large number. This happens in the following line.

```
engine::Shaderfile textured("../res/shaders/engine/textured.glsl", indices_rect);
```

I passed the vector just to see what happens inside the constructor. The beginning looks like this:

```
Shaderfile::Shaderfile(std::string path, const std::vector<unsigned>& v)
{
// Capacity gets set here
#ifdef _ENGINE_DEBUG
    _path = path;
#endif
    std::ifstream file;
    std::stringstream fs;
    file.exceptions(std::ifstream::badbit | std::ifstream::failbit);
...
```

But even before the line "_path = path" the capacity for **v** is over 1000000000. If anyone has an idea what the problem might be, please help.

Comment: We would need a [mcve] to know. Something is clearly overwriting data it shouldn’t.

Comment: What's calling the `ShaderFile` constructor? Something inside `textured` function? How is `set_default_texture` relevant?

Comment: @Quimby I don't really know, what's relevant. These are the only lines of code which are called from the initialization of the vector to the first encounter of the problem.

Comment: These cannot be the only lines called, because there's nothing that calls the constructor. Where is `indices_rect` assigned to `v`?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I couldn't reproduce the problem in a test project, it just seems to happens in the posted code from the engine project

Comment: @Quimby I don't really know what you mean. "textured" is an instance of Shaderfile and indices_rect is passed as a const reference to the constructor, so v is a const reference to indices_rect.

Comment: @AProgrammer Oh, sorry I thought it was a function declaration...What happens when you print `std::cout<<v.capacity()<<' '<<v.size();` as the first line in the ctor?

Comment: From the information you've given, it is virtually impossible for anyone to help.  There is clearly other code in your program - presumably executed before the code you have shown - that probably overwrites some memory it shouldn't.   The nature of undefined behaviour is that anything can happen.  Sometimes the "anything" includes "nothing seems to happen for a while, and then some unrelated code bombs out".   You will have to work backward by trial and error, eliminating some previously executed code, rebuilding, restarting the program, and seeing if the symptom disappears.

Comment: How are you checking the capacity?  Are you debugging an optimized build?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I'm running the Debugger in Visual Studio in the Debug Configuration for vc++

Comment: @Peter, well, if I don't create a Shaderfile object, it works. But the error happens before the first line in the constructor of the Shaderfile object.

Comment: @AProgrammer - My point is you need to go back further than that.   The culprit can be ANY code executed after program startup and BEFORE the place where you see a symptom (which you describe as "before the first line in the constructor of the Shaderfile object").

Comment: Alright guys, I figured out the issue. It was because of a preprocessor in Shaderfile.h. It was a condition to declare the _path variable which is set in the constructor, with the same preprocessor condition. Once I removed the condition in the headerfile it worked.

Comment: In the future, please make a [mcve] especially after you've been asked to do so. This is what it's like for us when we read your question: You: This code initializes the vector... Me: Ok, so you've created a simple vector. You: Then this static function gets called, it justs sets a string for a default path... Me: What string??? What default path??? I have no idea what you're talking about and what the function does. You: But immediately as I jump into the constructor for "Shaderfile", before the first line is executed, the capacity is set to said large number...

Comment: Me: What does this have to do with the constructor of `Shaderfile`? You: But even before the line "_path = path" the capacity for v is over 1000000000... Me: What does `_path` have to do with the size of the vector??? As you can see, you haven't given us enough information to help you or to even understand your problem at all. This is why we require MCVE's. Your problem turned out to be in some code that we know nothing about, and again, we still have no idea why it's related to the vector. So, please, read the page in the link and make an MCVE next time. Remember that we can't read minds.

Comment: @FeiXiang Well, I tried, as written, but I couldn't reproduce the problem simply because I've not thought about the preprocessor in the h file. Also, most of your questions were mine as well. I've specified what is important, you don't need to know what default path is set, it is not important in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a preprocessor condition in the header file. If a makro was defined, I would declare the _path variable and initialize it in the constructor with that same condition. Once I removed the condition in the header file it works.

**[Shaderfile.h] Before:**

```
...
private:
#ifdef _ENGINE_DEBUG
    std::string _path;
#endif
    std::array<std::string, 4> _sources;
...
```

**[Shaderfile.h] After:**

```
...
private:
    std::string _path;
    std::array<std::string, 4> _sources;
...
```

This simple change made it work. I still have the preprocessor condition in the constructor.

Comment: It appears that some of the source modules in your code are compiled with `_ENGINE_DEBUG` defined, and others are compiled without it.  This creates multiple different definitions for you ShaderFile class, violating the ODR.  The crash occurs because the constructor is expecting a `_path` variable, when the constructed object does not have it, and there is an `array` variable there instead (or it isn't expecting a `_path` when one is there).